# try catch issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

what's a better way of doing the below try catch? Currently I have each WMI field in its own try catch statement.

I do not want to put the whole class into a massive try catch as I have issues with fields not displaying anything back (tried this and does not work well for what I am doing).

I have about 25 other WMI fields that I need to put in and am wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this?

```
private void cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" + cmbHdd.SelectedItem + "'");
foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
{
    try
    {
        lblSystemName.Text = "SystemName: " + moDisk["systemname"];
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        lblSystemName.Text = "SystemName: WMI Error"; ;
    }
    try
    {
        lblType.Text = "Type: " + moDisk["MediaType"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    {

        lblType.Text = "Type: WMI Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you get exceptions there? I would work on the reason, not on symptoms.

Comment: It will generate exception only when moDisk["MediaType"] is null. But this can be blocked by using if else statement.

Comment: the problem is that if I have a WMI field of say "Availabilty" then one of the servers this will be run on will not have "availability" for what ever reason (which is fine). However the next WMI field after "Availability" might be "FirmwareVersion" (which does exist). However, since "Availability" returned a exception (the wmi class does not exists) then I have noticed that "FirmwareVersion" then displays nothing (even though it should). I was told that it is because I have a massive try catch in the method that is getting an exception and going straight to catch and not carrying on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper method:

```
private static string GetMOValue(ManagementObject mo, string name)
{
    try
    {
        object result = mo[name];
        return result == null ? "" : result.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return "WMI Error";
    }
}

...
lblSystemName.Text = GetMOValue(moDisk, "systemname");
lblType.Text = GetMOValue(moDisk, "MediaType");
```

Note you should probably catch a more specific exception (not sure what exceptions can be thrown by the ManagementObject indexer).

Comment: Thanks Joe - this worked a charm! This is so good I will put this in other coding I have!

Comment: How do I capture a specific exception actually - I know VS throws exception - should I just copy that exception and put it in the "exception" box - catch(EXCEPTION)

Comment: "How do I capture a specific exception actually" - if you put a breakpoint in the catch block, you can examine the exception that's thrown to get its type.  I suspect it's a `ManagementException` or `KeyNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 2):

I think erro occur when there is no data avaialbe for the given column in datatable

```
if (moDisk.Columns.Contains("systemname"))
{
  lblSystemName.Text = "SystemName: " + moDisk["systemname"]; 
}
else 
{
   lblSystemName.Text = "SystemName: WMI Error";
}
```

**Note : not sure this is datatable or not but you can code like this instead of catching exception for each value ... with the help of if ..else you can code this easily**

Comment: this is great but sorry I did not specifiy if I had a DB or not...I am not that advanced to work on DB's yet :-) this is a simple label that needs to be populated...although I will keep this as I might need this in case I have a DB requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I feel that using these many try catch is not good. If i were u i would have done in following method..if try catch really needed.

```
private void cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" + cmbHdd.SelectedItem + "'");
string current=  string.Empty;
foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
{
    try
    {
        current = "SystemName";
        lblSystemName.Text = "SystemName: " + moDisk["systemname"];


        current = "MediaType";  
        lblType.Text = "Type: " + moDisk["MediaType"].ToString();

    }
    catch(Exception)

     {
            //print "error in" + current;

}
}
```